# Swipe MultiChoice items GridView Android

Tags: android, swipe, android-gridview

I have code multichoice items gridview in android when swipe, but when I swipe diagonal line it usurpation other item. I want check when I swipe to center cell. but I can't. please help me.
[screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VrHp.png)

```
gridWordTable.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridWordTable.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    gridWordTable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int i = gridWordTable.pointToPosition((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
            if (i >= 0 && i < listCharater.length * listCharater.length) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    gridWordTable.getChildAt(i).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_selected));
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    gridWordTable.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.setSelected(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```